# How reliable is to be + past participle to identify passive voice?

Tags: past-participles, passive-voice, be

I am trying to write a software that can identify simple variants of passive voice in an english sentence.

I found multiple resources that state that `to be` + a `past participle` is an indication that the sentence is in passive voice.

My question is, is this a reliable rule?
Are there any false positives, i.e. are there sentences that contain a construct of `to be` + `past participle` that **are not** in passive voice?

Comment: See the linked question for the answer. Yes, there *is* a reliable way of always detecting the passive voice, and no, it is *not* as simple as "*to be* + past participle", you can quite easily construct any number of examples to the contrary.

Comment: @RegDwigнt: Thanks for the pointer. I rephrased the question so that it differs in scope and more matches the actual question title. Do you think it's still a duplicate?

Comment: Yes, I think I do. As the linked question shows, you need to meet *four* requirements. So by definition if you meet only one, that is not enough. I am perplexed. You are worried. He is amazed. We are flabbergasted. He was astonished. She is astounded. They were dumbfounded. I am trapped. I am stunned. I am unaffected. I wouldn't be surprised (there, that's another example right there) if there are more false positives than true positives.

Comment: Your comment is already quite helpful. I'm not a native english speaker so coming up with those examples is quite hard for me. Thanks for showing me those.